# Fitting a distribution to a Dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I have some vectors in matlab, with the empirical CDF, i can plot the CCDF for the data set, the plot gave a clu for the distribution:

```
[y,x]=ecdf(ISFFT);
X=log(x); Y=log(1-y);
plot(X,Y,'>-R','LineWidth',2);
```

After tht i said it coul be a log normal so:

FLN=fitdist(ISFFT,'lognormal'); gave me mu and sigma.

The matter is i don't know how to plot a ccdf for mu and sigma and compare it with the plot of the figure.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a set of values for the x axis

```
x = linspace(0,10,1000); %// for example
```

and then use [`logncdf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/logncdf.html) for the estimated `mu` and `sigma`:

```
y = logncdf(x,mu,sigma);
plot(x,1-y) %// CCDF is 1 -CDF
```